# Blower fan comes on once a week

Tags: thermostat, furnace, fans, heat, blower

I have basic two wire thermostat, one for power on for neutral. I only have central heat, not air.  My blower fan kicked on the last two sundays, but itself, but not today which is sunday.  It only happens on sunday.  My thermostat is programmable but I cannot use those features as it only has two wires going to it.  Is there any explanation why this is happening? It's just something that is bugging me because it doesn't make any sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a hidden/default program in the thermostat. Does the thermostat have batteries in it?

Comment: The wires are probably not common and neutral. they are probably R and W. R would be a 24V version of "power" and W would be "call for heat".  There aren't any other wires. There is no "call for blower".  If the blower is running, heat is on.  Why would a thermostat want heat on?

Comment: Yes the thermostat has batters, they were old and crappy batteries. I changed the batteries and it didn't come on today.  It's just weird that it was coming on only sunday mornings and no other time.  If it was bad batteries wouldn;t it just be coming on randomly and not just sunday mornings?

Comment: I changed the batteries and it hasn't happened.  Maybe it was just something with bad batteries.  Just weird how it would come on at the same time every week and the thermostat is wired t be a programmable thermostat.

Comment: Is it getting hot in your house at all...? a 2-wire stat means that the furnace has to switch the blower on/off on its own, and it does that through a thermostat in the plenum/bonnet of the furnace -- if that plenum 'stat/limit's on the fritz, it'd explain seemingly spontaneous blower operation

Comment: I'm not sure honestly if it was hot air or ambient air. It's just weird the it was only happening sundays at the same time.  I have changed the batteries out and it didn't happen today.

Comment: So I finally figured out what it was. My idiot landlord just put a dryer in the basement and didnt hook up the ventilation to it so all the hot ait is being vented in the basement. It;s turning the fan limit switch on and I think that's why the blower is running. I do my laundry on sundays. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Evan -- yeah, hot dryer exhaust impinging on the furnace is definitely a problem.  Is that dryer gas or electric BTW?  (I ask because your situation is either "this is *not* fine" or "OMGWTFBBQ" depending on which it is)

Comment: It is a electric dryer.  But this making the basement like 9o degrees would activate the blower motor right? It would heat up the limit switch and activate the blower

Comment: Would this make the hvac blower come on, the basement getting really hot like that?

Comment: @Evan -- if the plenum limit is on the fritz (cutting in too low), perhaps...I'd fix the dryer situation in any case, though, as it's putting a lot of lint and moisture into your basement right now